# How often does a planet with 3 moons have no moon in the sky?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am designing a planetary system for a role playing game with 3 moons with different orbits. I have created an excel spreadsheet to plan a day in the "current" year where all three moons are in the "new moon" or hidden from the planet stage but I wanted to know how to calculate just how rare this event was.  I would like a general purpose solution. I realize that with certain moon orbits the solution is simply it can't be possible (for example if they all have the same orbit).

I know that the system of equations for this problem is the following

$$M_1(t) = \left| (t + S_1 \mod P_1) - \frac {P_1}2\right|$$
$$M_2(t) = \left| (t + S_2 \mod P_2) - \frac {P_2}2\right|$$
$$M_3(t) = \left| (t + S_3 \mod P_3) - \frac {P_3}2\right|$$

Where:

$$M_1,M_2,M_3\text{ represent the current phase of the moon on a given day}$$
$$S_1,S_2,S_3\text{ represent the position of the moon at t=0}$$
$$P_1,P_2,P_3\text{ represent how many days it takes the moon to orbit the planet}$$

And I want to know for what values of t does $M_1=M_2=M_3=0$

As I said, I want a general formula if it exists (or at least a mechanism for solving it) to determine the period.  But I would be happy with just a specific solution for 
$$S_1=4,S_2=20,S_4=18,P_1=14,P_2=30,P_3=34$$

**EDIT: I had the wrong formula for the current phase, I forgot that it goes up and then down and not immediately back to 0**

**EDIT 2: I might be completely wrong about this whole methodology using this system of complex equations...if that's the case, I really just want to know the answer to my question "How often does a planet with 3 moons have no moon in the sky?"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To finde the $t$ such that all the phases are zero, you want the [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).  If $P_1,P_2,P_3$ have no common factor, there will be a solution every $P_1P_2P_3$ days.  If they do have a common factor, there will either be one every $LCM(P_1,P_2,P_3)$ days or not at all, depending on whether the phase differences share the common factor.

For edit 2, it is quite simple.  If every moon in in the sky $\frac 12$ of the time, each will also be missing $\frac 12$ of the time, and they will all be gone $\frac 18$ of the time.  The same Chinese remainder theorem says their absence is independent in the long term.

Comment: Thanks, with this information I was able to modify my spreadsheet and determine a moon pattern where a moonless night happens only once every approximately 20 years.

Answer (score 0):

To satisfy the first equation, $t=3+14k$.
To satisfy the second equation, $3+14k+20+15$ is a multiple of 30, so $14k+38$ is a multiple of 15, so  $8-k$ is a multiple of 15, $k=8+15q$.  And so on.